# How to check if a directory exists in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

How to check if a directory exists in Linux command line?

**Solution:**  `[ -d ¨a¨ ]&&echo ¨exists¨||echo ¨not exists¨`

Comment: So mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 46):

```
$ if test -d /the/dir; then echo "exist"; fi
```

Comment: I need it in command line, not in a script.

Comment: That is command line. You can type that into bash directly, or you can resume it to `test -d /the/dir`: `test -d /the/dir && echo "exist" || echo "does not exist"` but they are really the same.

Comment: Not everybody's shell is `bash`!

Comment: @reinierpost then good luck to you...

Comment: @Stefano Borini: I still use `tcsh` because I'm too lazy to rewrite my `.tcshrc`. But more to the point: this might have explained the OP's problem.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming your shell is BASH:

```
if [ -d /the/dir ]; then echo 'Exists'; else echo 'Not found'; fi
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: Then figure out what your shell is. Perhaps `csh` or `tcsh`?

Answer (score 11):

The canonical way is to use the **test(1)** utility:

```
test -d path && echo "Directory Exists"
```

where *path* is the pathname of the directory you want to check for.

**For example:**

```
test -d Desktop/ && echo "Directory Exists"
Directory Exists
test -d Desktop1/ && echo "Directory Exists"
# nothing appers
```

Comment: The command doesn't appear to be doing by itself but when joined with a `echo "Directory Exists"`.

Comment: @Steve Emmerson `test` is not a command. This is not working...

Comment: @ChamindaBandara then you have a non-compliant environment and/or operating system. Linux follows the Unix standard and that standard specifies the test(1) utility. See <https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/>.

Answer (score 9):

```
[ -d /home/bla/ ] && echo "exits"
```

Comment: Can I have something like ELSE, to show a text even if the directory does´n exists?

Comment: Workaround: `[ -d /home/bla/ ] && echo "exist" ; [ ! -d /home/bla/ ] && echo "doesnt exist" `

Answer (score 2):

`[ -d "YOUR_DIR" ] && echo "is a dir"`

e.g.:

`[ -d / ] && echo "root dir`"

will output: `root dir`.

Comment: [-d: command not found   this is what I get

Comment: Between "[" and "-" MUST be a space. This should work on Bourne and Bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a directory exists in a shell script you can use the following:

```
dir=$1

if [ -d "$dir" ]; then

 #means that $dir exists.

fi
```

to check the opposite , add `!` before the `-d ->[ ! -d ....]`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just `ls` it:

```sh
ls my/directory/
```

If it exists, you'll see its contents, if it doesn't exist you'll see an error like this:

```
ls: cannot access 'my/directory': No such file or directory
```